# Why can't this simple javascript/jquery code alert selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't explain the behaviour of the code below.   Here's my entire script

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var tmpText = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
        tmpText = '';
        $('#btn_bold').click(function(){alert(tmpText);});
        $('textarea').bind('mouseup', function(){
                  tmpText = '';
                  if(window.getSelection){
                    tmpText = window.getSelection();
                  }else if(document.getSelection){
                    tmpText = document.getSelection();
                  }else if(document.selection){
                    tmpText = document.selection.createRange().text;
                  }
                //tmpText = 'hello world';
                alert(tmpText);
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn_bold">click</button>
<textarea>This is some text</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Try the following operations:

1) Use your mouse to high light text in the text area.  You will notice that javascript alerts you the selected text.

2) Press the click button.  You will notice javascript will alert you an empty string.

No uncomment `tmpText = 'hello world';` and repeat the above steps.   This time, you'll notice both steps 1) and 2) alerts you "hello world".

How come in the first experiment, step 2) does not alert you the same text as step 1)?

**I am testing in google chrome**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it doesn't automatically get converted to string. When you call it straight with alert(), it runs the toString on it, but when you assign to a variable to be later used, it keeps it as selection object and when you try to alert it later on, you presumably won't have that selection active anymore (because you just clicked the button).

Add toString() at the end of each of those selections and it should work as intended.

```
if(window.getSelection){
                    tmpText = window.getSelection().toString();
                  }else if(document.getSelection){
                    tmpText = document.getSelection().toString();
                  }else if(document.selection){
                    tmpText = document.selection.createRange().text;
                  }
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/VsvBm/)

I recall this being explained quite well in the mozilla developer pages under the getSelection bit, if you want a better explanation why it is like this.

EDIT: found the link to the page on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection), specifically check what they say under "Notes".

Comment: Subsequently: before adding .toString() I copied the code and added an <INPUT> with a setInterval event that called `$("#in").val(tmpText)` every 500ms, and the correct tmpText showed up as long as there was a selection in the TEXTAREA, but it was cleared as soon as it was blurred.  The tmpText var referred to the *selection object*, which was updated to have a zero-length value when the TEXTAREA lost its selection.

Comment: Exactly, which would also explain the empty value when clicking the button, as the selection would get removed at that point.

Comment: While this is true, it isn't the fundamental problem, which is that textarea selections work differently in most browsers (using the textarea's `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties).

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, the selection within a textarea (or text input) is handled differently to the selection in the main body of the page. To get the selected text within a textarea, you can use the following, which works in all major browsers:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxN7p/

Code:

```
function getTextareaSelectedText(textarea) {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof textarea.selectionStart == "number") {
        text = textarea.value.slice(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd);
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "none" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii...

you have to convert to string the selection... example

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

otherwise you wont could access to the data