# Build textarea with formatting controls - how to get selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just for fun, I want to build simple text formatting tools for a textarea.  To begin, I want to be able to enclose high-lighted text in a textarea with ** if it is to be in bold format (just like stackoverflow's textarea editor).  I've written the following code, which works most of the time, but it does have a bug, which I'll explain shortly.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var tmpText = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
        tmpText = '';
        $('#btn_bold').click(function(){bold(tmpText);});
        $('textarea').bind('mouseup', function(){
                  tmpText = '';
                  if(window.getSelection){
                    tmpText = window.getSelection().toString();
                  }else if(document.getSelection){
                    tmpText = document.getSelection().toString();
                  }else if(document.selection){
                    tmpText = document.selection.createRange().text;
                  }
        });
});

function bold(str)
{
        $('textarea').val($('textarea').val().replace(str,'**'+str+'**'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn_bold">bold it</button>
<textarea>AA</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

So if you high-light the first letter A and bold it, you'll get the result `**A**A`.  But if you high-light the second letter A and bold it, you still get `**A**A`, instead of `A**A**` because the line of code `$('textarea').val($('textarea').val().replace(str,'**'+str+'**'));` is insufficient at identifying which letter A you want to bold.

What's an efficient way to identify high-lighted text and bold it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a [jQuery plug-in that does this](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) that I can extract out to a standalone script if it would help.  An example of using the plugin to replace selected text with the word "hello".

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://rangyinputs.googlecode.com/files/textinputs_jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('textarea').bind('mouseup',function() { $(this).replaceSelectedText('hello');});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea style="width:300px; height:300px;">
AAA
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, [as I commented in a related question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170581/why-cant-this-simple-javascript-jquery-code-alert-selected-text/6170819#6170819), the function you have there won't work for textareas, which have a separate mechanism for dealing with selections. See my answer there for a function that will work.

Comment: i'm trying out your plugin. Can you show me a few lines of jquery code on how to instantiate your object and use the replaceSelectedText() function?

Answer (score 0):

The selection object returns the string if you call tostring() on it.  You can also get the range object, which has more information about the starting and ending points.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection

and

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164093/javascript-wrap-text-with-tag/6164403#6164403), you could do it like this:

```
el = document.getElementById('texty');
  if (el.setSelectionRange) {

     el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart) + "**" + el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd) + "**" + el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);

  }
  else if(document.selection.createRange()) {
      document.selection.createRange().text = "**" + document.selection.createRange().text + "**"; 
  }
```

However, note that this method is limited to textareas.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function formatText(el,tagstart,tagend) {
      if (el.setSelectionRange) {
        el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart) + tagstart +
        el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd) + tagend +
        el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length)
      } else {
        // IE code 
        var selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
        var tag="b"
        if (selectedText != "") {
          var newText = "<" + tag + ">" + selectedText + "</" + tag + ">";
          document.selection.createRange().text = newText;
        }
      }
    }
</head>
<body>
  <p> <textarea rows="30" cols="59" name="Write-my-life-moments" 
       id="write-my-life- moments"></textarea> </p>

  <input type="button" value="BOLD"  
     onclick="formatText(document.getElementById('write-my-life-moments'), 
     '<b>','</b>')" />
</body>
```

This Code Works For FF, IE(6)> , Opera 9>, Safari. I Tested It On these Browsers. not on Old ones. So please Check this on old browsers. i dont get time to check it on old browsers (It Does not show my text area opening tag y? i don't know, so please dd yourself. **write-my-life-moments**. it is name of text area) `

Comment: I don't see how this javascript ever worked correctly. There are syntax errors (missing semicolons).